# Proving simple group theory fact

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ subgroups of $G$. Then the product set $HK =\{hk | h \in H, k \in K \}$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH$.

My attempt thus far is below:

If $HK = KH$ then we show $HK$ is a subgroup as follows. For every $h_1,h_2 \in H$ and for every $k_1,k_2 \in K$ we have
$$h_1k_1h_2k_2 = h_1(k_1h_2)k_2 \stackrel{(1)}{=} h_1h'k'k_2 \in HK$$

where in (1) we've used that $HK = KH \implies k_1h_2 = h'k'$ for some $h',k'$. Thus we have shown closure. Associativity is immediate from the fact on $G$. $ee = e \in HK$ so we have the existence of the identity. Finally for any $hk \in HK$ we have from $KH=HK$ that there are some $h',k'$ such that $k^{-1}h^{-1} = h'k' \in HK$, so we have the existence of inverses.

Conversely, suppose $HK$ a subgroup so that for every $h_1,h_2 \in H$ and for every $k_1,k_2 \in K$ we have by the closure of $HK$ that $h_1k_1h_2k_2=hk \in HK$ for some $h \in H, k \in K$. Now we want to show first that $KH \subset HK$. For any $k'h' \in KH$ fix $h_2 = h', k_1 = k'$ so that for every $h_1, k_2$ we have some $h \in H, k \in K$ such that $k_1h_2=h_1^{-1}hkk_2^{-1} \in HK$ by the closure of $H$ and $K$ individually. Conversely, if we want to show that $HK \subset KH$ then take any $h'k' \in HK$ to begin...$\textbf{but I cannot complete this last step}.$

Should I show that $HK$ a subgroup implies $KH$ a subgroup and then use the above argument? This seems very circuitous but I don't see a way to isolate $h'k'$ in my $h_1k_1h_2k_2=hk \in HK$ equation above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is NOT for homework. As should be clear from my post history, I am self-studying.

Edit 2: Conversely, if we want to show that $HK \subset KH$ then take any $h'k' \in HK$ to begin. Fix $h_2 = h'^{-1}, k_1 = k'^{-1}$, so that we have for every $h_1, k_2$ some $h \in H, k \in K$ such that $k'^{-1}h'^{-1}=h_1^{-1}hkk_2^{-1}$ so that by the existence of inverses in $G$ we have $h'k' = (k'^{-1}h'^{-1})^{-1}=(h_1^{-1}hkk_2^{-1})^{-1} = k_2k^{-1}h^{-1}h_1^{-1} \in KH$, so we are done.

Comment: Invert everything. Then $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}$. The map $h\mapsto h^{-1}$ is a bijection, so proving one containment proves the other.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Please see the attached, does my edit seem to make sense?

Comment: You can be quicker. If $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, then $hk\in HK$. We need $hk\in KH$. But $hk$ is the inverse of some element in $HK$, say $h'k'$. Then $hk=(h'k')^{-1}=k'^{-1}h'^{-1}\in KH$.